# How to retrieve and update the checkbox status from different controller in grails?

Tags: grails, illegalargumentexception

I have a PlanAction controller and volunteer controller. 
PlanAction has many volunteer and volunteer belongs to planAction.
I want to create a volunteer depending on the checkboxes a user ticks that represent separate planAction.

I tried remoteFunction but couldn't get it to work as on remoteFunction didn't really make a call to the toggleBusCheck method.

planAction create gsp has the following syntex for calling remote function with id and params to create a volunteer

```
<g:each in="${familyValueInstance?.planAction}" status="p" var="action">
                    <p>

                    <g:checkBox name='volunteer' value="${action.id}" checked="" onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'volunteer', action:'toggleBusCheck', id:action.id)}" /> ${action.actionsup}</p>

                  </g:each>
```

method in volunteer controller

```
def toggleBusCheck = {
    volunteerInstance = new Volunteer(params)
    volunteerInstance.userAccount = UserAccount.get(session.selectedUser.id)
    volunteerInstance.planAction = params.planAction
    if (!volunteerInstance.hasErrors() && volunteerInstance.save(flush:true)) {
     flash.message = "familyValue.created"
     flash.defaultMessage = "Volunteer Created"
     redirect(action: "planList") 
    }
    redirect(action: "planList") 
  }
```

this is error i am getting when i try to check if a call is made to the toggleBusCheck method

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke whanauora.values.Volunteer.setPlanAction on bean class 'class whanauora.values.Volunteer' - java.lang.ClassCastException@4c1232f6 - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "whanauora.values.PlanAction"
```

Comment: I am down to this error now...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke whanauora.values.Volunteer.setPlanAction on bean class 'class whanauora.values.Volunteer' - java.lang.ClassCastException@4c1232f6 - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "whanauora.values.PlanAction"

Comment: Please include your code that will help to give solution\

Comment: @Anantha I have updated the main question with the code now.. thanks

Comment: You didn't give controller is volunteer and action is toggleBusCheck  in remoteFunction.What is business controller and saveAction.

Comment: In PlanAction create, we click the checkbox(s), according to that volunteer object(s) going to create. After creation of volunteer(s), planAction list is rendered. Here no need of ajax. Bz list is another page.

Comment: In planaction create, add one submit button.in button click call javascript function that can get all checked values and copy that all check box values with comma separator into one string variable.

Comment: then pass this variable to controller action using remote function.that action read the string variable and using split function get the ids and create volunteer(s) and render list page

Comment: much appreciated @Anantha I will give it a go and get back to you.